# Is there a better way to represent provenenace on a field level in SOLR

Tags: solr

I have documents in SOLR which consist of fields where the values come from different source systems. The reason why I am doing this is because this document is what I want returned from the SOLR search, including functionality like hit highlighting. As far as I know, if I use join with multiple SOLR documents, there is no way to get what matched in the related documents. My document has fields like:

```
id => unique entity id
type => entity type
name => entity name
field_1_s => dynamic field from system A
field_2_s => dynamic field from system B
...
```

Now, my problem comes when data is updated in one of the source systems. I need to update or remove only the fields that correspond to that source system and keep the other fields untouched. My thought is to encode the dynamic field name with the first part of the field name being a 8 character hash representing the source system.. this way they can have common field names outside of the unique source hash. And in this way, I can easily clear out all fields that start with the source prefix, if needed.

Does this sound like something I should be doing, or is there some other way that others have attempted?

Answer (score 0):

In our experience the easiest and least error prone way of implementing something like this is to have a straight forward way to build the resulting document, and then reindex the complete document with data from both subsystems retrieved at time of reindexing. Tracking field names and field removal tend to get into a lot of business rules that live outside of where you'd normally work with them.

By focusing on making the task of indexing a specific document easy and performant, you'll make the system more flexible regarding other issues in the future as well (retrieving all documents with a certain value from Solr, then triggering a reindex for those documents from a utility script, etc.).

That way you'll also have the same indexing flow for your application and primary indexing code, so that you don't have to maintain several sets of indexing code to do different stuff.

If the systems you're querying isn't able to perform when retrieving the number of documents you need, you can add a local cache (in SQL, memcached or something similar) to speed up the process, but that code can be specific to the indexing process. Usually the subsystems will be performant enough (at least if doing batch retrieval depending on the documents that are being updated).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The process we are doing now is where there is some ETL specific to the source system that pushes data out, as opposed to something querying all systems and pulling a document together. So, to incorporate your suggestion, we would keep the pushed data staged, and have some process re-create the document from the staged data. I could stage in separate SOLR instances, and then merge them into a single one. Any thoughts on that approach?